# Is there a shortcut in Finale to enter in the Simple Edit Tool mode?

Tags: finale

I know that, for instance, in order to access the Selection Tool mode, you can hit `ctrl + shift + A`. Does it exist a similar shortcut for the Simple Edit Tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Finale you can create your own shortcuts:

https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2012Mac/Content/Finale/IDD_KEY_SHORTS.htm

and

https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2014Mac/Content/Finale/Simple_Other_Simple_Edit_Commands.htm

**Windows:**

Esc => tool selection mode

tab => simple entry (pitch tool: ô)

from here you can with Alt and numbers 1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7 select the note values.

https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2014Win/Content/Finale/IDD_SIMPLE_OPTIONS.htm